# DB scripts to launch in WSO2 IS + WSO2 APIM

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2, wso2-identity-server

I have deployed WSO2ISasKM with WSO2APIM and I'm struggling to get the configuration right.
I can see there are a lot of scripts in the ../dbscripts folder. However, since I only share config+governance registry and userdb I created 2 dbs in which I only ran the script wso2is-km-5.7.0\dbscripts\postgresql.sql that created UM_ and REG_ tables. I am keeping the local registry in the WSO2CARBON_DB (H2). Is this correct?
I don't really make any use of scripts about IDENTITY and CONSENT that are shipped with the wso2IS binaries. Where should those scripts be launched?
I'm asking because there are some strange behaviour and errors about content in my logs.
This is how i configured the registry.xml of both IS and APIM:

```
    <currentDBConfig>wso2registry</currentDBConfig>
    <readOnly>false</readOnly>
    <enableCache>true</enableCache>
    <registryRoot>/</registryRoot>

    <dbConfig name="wso2registry">
        <dataSource>jdbc/WSO2CarbonDB</dataSource>
    </dbConfig>
    <dbConfig name="sharedregistry">
        <dataSource>jdbc/WSO2REG_DB</dataSource>
    </dbConfig>
<remoteInstance url="https://fqdn of the IS/APIM:9443/registry">
   <id>sharedreg</id>
   <cacheId>reg_db_owner@jdbc:postgresql://carbondb.postgresql-wso2.com:5432/wso2_carbon_shared_reg</cacheId>
   <dbConfig>sharedregistry</dbConfig>
   <readOnly>false</readOnly>
   <enableCache>true</enableCache>
   <registryRoot>/</registryRoot>
</remoteInstance>

    <mount path="/_system/governance" overwrite="true">
        <instanceId>sharedreg</instanceId>
        <targetPath>/_system/governance</targetPath>
    </mount>
        <mount path="/_system/config" overwrite="true">
        <instanceId>sharedreg</instanceId>
        <targetPath>/_system/config</targetPath>
    </mount>
```

This is how datasources got added in master-datasources.xml

```
<datasource>
            <name>WSO2REG_DB</name>
            <description>REGDB ON POSTGRES</description>
            <jndiConfig>
                <name>jdbc/WSO2REG_DB</name>
            </jndiConfig>
            <definition type="RDBMS">
                <configuration>
                    <url>jdbc:postgresql://carbondb.postgresql-wso2.com:5432/wso2_carbon_shared_reg</url>
                    <username>wso2</username>
                    <password>wso2</password>
                    <defaultAutoCommit>true</defaultAutoCommit>
                    <driverClassName>org.postgresql.Driver</driverClassName>
                    <maxActive>50</maxActive>
                    <maxWait>60000</maxWait>
                    <testOnBorrow>true</testOnBorrow>
                    <validationQuery>SELECT 1</validationQuery>
                    <validationInterval>30000</validationInterval>
                </configuration>
            </definition>
         </datasource>
```

The UM_DB entry is identical but it point to another database.
I also noticed that for REG_DB and UM_DB, with Postgresql-11, I have to set the `defaultAutocommit` must be set to `true` to avoid error in writing the registry.

Can you also explain what are the purpose of IDENTITY and CONSENT related tables?I read the docs but couldn't understand the practical use of them.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using APIM with IS as KM, you need to share AM_DB as well. The script is inside `dbscripts/apimgt/`. That script includes both Identity and Consent scripts. So you can ignore Identity and Consent scripts.

See more in: https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/Configuring+WSO2+Identity+Server+as+a+Key+Manager

Comment: thanks for the answer. What about the `defaultautocommit` element for Postgres? Should i set it to true for UM_DB and REG_DB? I can see in the docs that you suggest setting it to `true` only for IS 5.7 and only for carbon_db.

Comment: if i am installing identity server 5.7 without api manager, should i run the dbscripts/apimgt/ as well? note: i am using ndb cluster. can you point to the correct scripts to install?